# hibernate column name issues

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

```
@Column(name="DateOfBirth")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

I specifically need the above code to create a column named "DateOfBirth," instead Hibernate gives me a column named date_of_birth.  How can I change this?  Is there a web.xml property?  I came across DefaultNamingStrategy and ImprovedNamingStrategy, but not sure how to specify one or the other.

Comment: Possible workaournd. If you name it dateofbirth the column in the DB would be named like that, but the attribute name should be the same.

Comment: Let me put it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround: if you name it `dateofbirth` the column in the DB would be named like that, but the attribute name should be the same.

Hibernate takes the camel case format to create/read database columns.

I've had this problem before. I worked with a legacy columns where there was no space in the column names "employeename", "employeerole", "departmentlocation". I hate it because all my beans properties had to be without camel case.

Database columns separated by "_" will be used to properly camelCase as you have just seen.

Answer (score 42):

Try putting this in

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 34):

FYI: The reason for the insertion of underscores is probably because you're using an [ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html). It's set on your [Configuration](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setNamingStrategy(org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy)) object. See [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19838.html) for an example...

If you don't want the underscores you can just not set the naming strategy, or set it to the DefaultNamingStrategy you discovered earlier.

Comment: That is exactly the cause of this problem. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me. Can you suggest any link to see what I will be missing while using DefaultNamingStrategy over Improved one?

Answer (score 10):

add below property in the case of spring boot.

**spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl**

Comment: This used to work but since spring-boot 2 (2.0.4) and hibernate 5.2 (5.2.17) it does not work anymore. I debugged through entire hibernate and the naming strategies actually do not interfere but some other hibernate magic afterwards does the transformation to add underscores to camlCase properties. This really sucks especially that an explicit @Column(name="nameWithCamlCase") does not help and hibernate still thinks to be smarter than what the developer wanted. I assume some latest JPA compliance issue is causing this madness.

Answer (score 7):

Put the @Column annotation on the getter:

```
@Column(name="DateOfBirth")
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The workaround proposed was to use @Column(name="dateofbirth"), which worked for my purposes.

Comment: Are you saying that the only change you made was in the capitalization?

Comment: Yeah.  It seems that ImprovedNamingStrategy was the perpetrator, which sees camelcase column names and converts into lowercase+underscores.  Bug or feature, you decide.

Answer (score 5):

ImprovedNamingStrategy has method addUnderscores() which is called from tableName() and columnName()
you can implement your own naming strategy class and override these as per your choice

```
    public class MyOwnNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {
        @Override
        public String tableName(String tableName) {
        //return addUnderscores(columnName); // skip this
        return columnName; // if you want column name variable name same
        //return changeAsYouWant(columnName); // as name sames
       }
   }
```

Comment: I would suggest also calling "super(tableName)" on any tablenames you do not need your special convention... maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate either fields or getter methods, it doesn't make a difference.  Can you post your full hibernate.cfg.xml or persistence.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but don't you need to annotate the get method and not the private variable?

Comment: I don't think so? At the very least, I can specify things like length at the instance variable level and they will alter the columns accordingly..

Comment: You can annotate either one, but you must annotate them consistently. If you mix them and annotate some headers and some getters, it will find one and ignore the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and adding the following two properties to my application.properties solved my issue: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl` `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` .