# Missing column that contains an underscore when trying to use Hibernate to map Date field

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, timestamp

I have a JPA TableXXX class that contains the following field:

```
@Column(name = "CreatedOn")
@NotNull
private Date createdOn;
```

When I compile and deploy my app it throws an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: created_on in TABLEXXX
```

I am using Hibernate 3.5.5 and Oracle 10g. the CreatedOn column is stored as Timestamp in the database.
Why does Hibernate add an underscore between 'created' and 'on'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check that you're not using a custom naming strategy other than the default one for EJB3. A custom naming strategy would be declared using the `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` property (could be in the `persistence.xml` or programatically, depending on how you use JPA).

#### References

- Hibernate EntityManager Reference Guide

  - [2.2.2. Bootstrapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html)
- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [3.6. Implementing a NamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy)

Comment: Thank you. I also find this link:                                                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376093/hibernate-column-name-issues                                                               and follow the advice there to use DefaultNamingStrategy.