# Spring Data doesn't seem to understand @Column name

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring-boot 1.4.1.RELEASE, with Spring Data and Hibernate to persist some data into a MySQL database.

I have this class, `Respondent`, annotated with `@Entity` and one of the fields annotated as below:

```
@Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String firstName;
```

When I try to save a Respondent to the DB by calling `save()` on its `CrudRepository<Respondent, Long>`, I get this error:

```
ERRORcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list'
```

This error had started occurring before I had the `@Column` annotation for the field, so I thought it was some default Hibernate behaviour to map firstName to first_name, but I've added the `@Column` annotation to it and nothing changed. Is it still wrong? I've already rebuilt the application with `mvn clean package`.

Here's my Respondent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Respondent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String firstName;
    private String tussenvoegsel;
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;
```

Comment: are you sure that the column "firstName" exists? also, usually i neve use any declared filed in the @entity class that is not annotated, like "private String tussenvoegsel;"

Comment: 100% sure. It's first_name that doesn't exist and to which somehow hibernate is still mapping my field.

Comment: try to change `@Column(name = "firstName"` to lowercase `@Column(name = "firstname"`.

Comment: seems you have a ImproveNamingStrategy set in your configuration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376093/hibernate-column-name-issues. Could you post your hibernate configuration class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Spring `uses jpa.SpringNamingStrategy` to generate the table names.

The `ImprovedNamingStrategy` will convert `CamelCase` to `SNAKE_CASE` where as the `EJB3NamingStrategy` just uses the table name unchanged.

You can try to change the `naming_strategy` to:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

or the `@Column name` attribute should be in lowercase `@Column(name = "firstname")`

---

For `Hibernate 5` this should work (I am not quite sure if you also need the above one. But try it with both):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting it to my application.properties, but the error persists. It seems there's a problem with that naming strategy in hibernate 5, which is what I'm using:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2763

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine updated the answer for hibernate 5 properties. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

There we need to follow some naming strategy.

The column name should be in lowercase or uppercase.

```
 @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;
```

or

```
@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstName;
```

keep in mind that, if you have your column name "first_name" format in the database then you have to follow the following way

```
@Column(name="firstName")
private String testName;
```