# Name of column in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How I can set name of column, like this: "firstName"

Now, when I do:

```
@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;
```

Hibernate take/create a column by name "first_name".

Comment: Did you by any chance put annotations on the getters as well?

Comment: No, I try also to put this on the getters, the same effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate column name issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376093/hibernate-column-name-issues)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on `NamingStragegy` that is being used for Hibernate configuation (explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html)). You probably have `camel case to lower case with underscore` strategy defined and hence, Hibernate is converting the column names to lower case with underscores.

If you are using Spring then you can set the naming strategy in `application.properties` as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

For Hibernate, [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy) article explains how to set the naming strategy in configuration.