# HibernateException: Missing column: Wrong name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, naming

In my Java code, I have a field named `isNegative` with a similar column existing in database. But Hibernate insists the name should be `is_negative`, even with forcing the name with `@Column`.

```
@Column(name="isNegative")
private boolean isNegative;
```

Error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column:
>   is_negative in datasource.item

Application.properties:

```
#JPA
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer=allow
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Comment: Can you show file `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `application.properties` in case you use Hibernate and Spring Framework together, or `persistence.xml` in case you use Hibernate as a JPA implement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate column name issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376093/hibernate-column-name-issues)

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, totally; but the thing is the mitigation doesn't work. I set the naming strategy to physicalNamingStrategyStandard; but it doesn't work.
The workaround (writing @column(name="isnegative")) works; but it is too much to do so for all my column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to your configuration, because you are setting  `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` to `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` which will use underscores for the names.

If you check the [**Configure Hibernate Naming Strategy** section of Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy), you can see that:

> Hibernate uses two different naming strategies to map names from the object model to the corresponding database names. The fully qualified class name of the physical and the implicit strategy implementations can be configured by setting the `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy` properties, respectively. Alternatively, if `ImplicitNamingStrategy` or `PhysicalNamingStrategy` beans are available in the application context, Hibernate will be automatically configured to use them.
>
> By default, Spring Boot configures the physical naming strategy with
>   `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`. This implementation provides the same
>   table structure as Hibernate 4: **all dots are replaced by underscores
>   and camel casing is replaced by underscores as well**. By default, all
>   table names are generated in lower case, but it is possible to
>   override that flag if your schema requires it.

To solve that you need to remove this property and use  the default naming strategy instead:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the solution?

Comment: No use `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy` instead check my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy and spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy

Adding following

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

to application.properties could help. This solution would work from hibernate 5.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below my analysis:

If you don't want your naming strategy to add an underscore to the column name or class name, then the strategy that you need to use would look like: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`. The things that you provide in annotations `@Table` and `@Column’s` name attribute would remain as it is. E.g. **firstName** attribute in entity will get a column name as **firstName** i.e. No change.

If you don't want to provide annotations and want to manually handle the table name and column names, you should extend the class `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` and override the required methods. If you still use annotations for some of the cases here, remember the overridden methods will apply on the names written in those annotations. `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=example.CustomStrategy`